# Apache Django Ajax time or size limit

Tags: ajax, django, time

My ajax responses seem to die out now that I am sending so much data in response to a search form request.  I'm using Django with Apache and Firefox and Chrome noth die out if I don't limit my search to few enough results.  What's the time or size limit to an Ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific limit relating to AJAX. However, if you have a lot of data which you are generating, a browser will timeout if you wait to massage all of the data into a suitable form (whether JSON, XML or HTML) before sending it all out. If you are using an auto-complete type query, generally it's enough to limit the matching entries to around a dozen. If it's a more conventional search, you can use [pagination](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) for the results page. Alternatively you might need to use a generator-like approach for page generation, though that might make setting a `Content-Length` header a little challenging.

Answer (score 0):

For a search page, do [django-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/) with [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/).